# Объединение модулей в android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, модули

Здравствуйте,

пишу андроид приложение в котором используется достаточно большое количество модулей (android stidio). Под модулем я подразумеваю отдельную часть проекта, которую в android studio можно создать как **File->New->New Module...**

Можно ли модули как-то сгруппировать, например объединить часть модулей в каталог, что бы при виде проекта "Android" (наряду с видами "Project", "Scratches" и пр.) часть модулей были сгруппированы ?

Заранее, спасибо всем за ответы.

Comment: Если вы переключитесь на вид структуры `Project`, то увидите структуру каталогов проекта. Вы можете самостоятельно распределить модули по папкам.

Comment: @metalurgus, дело в том что  вид структуры "Project" содержит большое количество не нужных файлов, которые мешают, и при разработке гораздо удобнее работать с видом "Android". Поэтому хотелось узнать есть ли именно в этом виде структуры проекта такая функция объединяющая модули.